# Type 'CanDeactivate' is not generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Following the Angular 2 example [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). There is can error right after the `implements` while running tsc:

> error TS2315: Type 'CanDeactivate' is not generic.

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }    from 'rxjs/Observable';
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
 canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

This is confusing to me, as the interface has already been declared. Why do I see an error there?

Comment: Likely you are using old router module (which has non-generic CanDeactivate interface). Could you check your package.json if it's the right version?

Comment: @HarryNinh I am using beta17. I think it is the latest angular version on npm..

Comment: Nope, the latest angular2 version is RC4, and latest @angular/router if I'm not wrong is 3.0.0-beta2 (`"@angular/router": "^3.0.0-beta.2"`). Anyway, you can check the export interface in `node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts`. If it is not something like `CanDeactivate<T>`, I think you're on the wrong version.

Comment: OK thank you @HarryNinh